# Prisma contains clause in where on array of strings

Tags: node.js, prisma

I have the following request payload which is passed as values for filters

```
filters: {
    "name": ["Joh", "Matt"]
}
```

Consider that this is the data that I have in the database

```
name
____
John
Jane
```

Is there a way in Prisma by which I can return partial matches based on any of the filter values in the array (in this case return `John`)

I have been passing the following filter object the where clause for single filter values but not sure how to do it when I have multiple values/array to check for

```
name: {
   contains: filters.name,
   mode: "insensitive",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that we create the `user` table with `name` column that has two rows like below:

```
const user = await prisma.user.createMany({
  data: [
    {
      name: "John"
    },
    {
      name: "Jane"
    }
  ]
});
```

To search for multiple values, you would do something like below:

```
const getUser = await prisma.user.findMany({
  where:{
    OR: [
      {
        name: {
          contains: 'Joh',
        },
      },
      {
        name: {
          contains: 'Matt',
        },
      },
    ]
  },
})
console.log(getUser);
```

The output is

```
[ { id: 4, name: 'John' } ]
```

To learn more about search, check out the prisma [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#search)

Answer (score 0):

Tried to find an answer, no success. Here are the methods for scalar list:

https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#scalar-list-methods

The hasSome was what I was looking for. Looks like they didn't make any method to find a string in the list by partial.

Such methods exists in Drizzle (arrayContains) or MongoDB.